# Getting Error Unable to translate bytes [96] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode. C#

Tags: c#

When passing below data getting error as Getting Error  Unable to translate bytes [96] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode. C#

```
request.medicareCardNumber = Medino.Text;
                request.dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(Birth.Text);
/*---
               string date = Birth.Text;
               string datecon = "";
               datecon = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("ddMMMyyyy");
               request.dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(datecon);
                ---*/
                request.givenName = GName.Text;
                request.familyName = FName.Text;
              //  request.medicareIRN = IRNNo.Text;// optional. Please provide any value otherwise comment out this code as sending blank IRN in the request returns format error.
                var input = "0x01, 0x02, 0x03";
```

```
    var array = input
                    .Split(',')
                    .Select(i => i.Trim().Replace("0x", ""))
                    .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(i, 16))
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Where exactly you get the exception? The LINQ expression with the input you provided works fine for me.

Comment: You are filling an object called request and then do some linq stuff on a string called input. Those two code parts are completely independent of each other? What are you trying to show? Show only the parts relevant to the problem and that actually shows the problem we might try ourselves then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting it to bytes, you can also define a byte array.

```cs
byte[] array = new byte[3] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
```